# Nested for loop with if condition in xml, Python

Tags: python, xml, if-statement, elementtree

I want to return `AA_code` when user enters `CHAIN_ID` and `RES_POSITION`.
`CHAIN_ID` is subelement of `CHAIN` tag and `RES_POSITION` and `AA_CODE` are
subelements of `RESIDUE` tag. `RESIDUE` tag is also subelement of `CHAIN`
tag.

My code returns `AA_CODE` only for `CHAIN_ID = "A"` and until
`RES_POSITION = "370"`. 
However it doesn't return for other `CHAIN_IDs` but
it should return. I couldn't understand the reason why, any help will
be appreciated.

PS:Im using Elementtree.

XML sample:

```
<RESIDUE>
         <RES_POSITION>370</RES_POSITION>
         <AA_CODE>G</AA_CODE>
      </RESIDUE>
   </CHAIN>
   <CHAIN>
      <CHAIN_ID>B</CHAIN_ID>
      <RESIDUE>
         <RES_POSITION>371</RES_POSITION>
         <AA_CODE>S</AA_CODE>
      </RESIDUE>
```

> My code which returns true result:

```
   chain = [seq for seq in SEQ.findall('CHAIN') if seq.findtext('CHAIN_ID') == "A"]
    print(chain)
    sequence = [res for res in SEQ.find('CHAIN') if res.findtext('RES_POSITION') == "370"]
    print(sequence)
    for seq in chain:
            for res in sequence:
                if res in seq:
                    print(res.findtext('AA_CODE'))
```

Returns:

```
[<Element 'CHAIN' at 0x0000019203C83138>]
        [<Element 'RESIDUE' at 0x00000192040E4C78>]
        G
```

> My code for CHAIN_ID as B:

```
chain = [seq for seq in SEQ.findall('CHAIN') if seq.findtext('CHAIN_ID') == "B"]
print(chain)
sequence = [res for res in SEQ.find('CHAIN') if res.findtext('RES_POSITION') == "371"]
print(sequence)
for seq in chain:
        for res in sequence:
            if res in seq:
                print(res.findtext('AA_CODE'))
```

Returns:

```
[<Element 'CHAIN' at 0x000002EFB2254DB8>]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sequence = [res for res in SEQ.find('CHAIN') if res.findtext('RES_POSITION') == "371"]
```

Here, you write `SEQ.find(...)` instead of `SEQ.findall(...)`.

Is this what you intended? find() only finds the first occurrence of CHAIN in your XML file, and my guess is, that the second part of the line (res_position == 371) will evaluate to False for the element found, so sequence will end up an an empty list.

Also, while findall returns CHAIN elements, findall returns only CHAIN sub-elements, which requires the if-part of the generator statement to be adapted.

Here's some code that I've actually tested ;-):

```
chain = [seq for seq in SEQ.findall('CHAIN') if seq.findtext('CHAIN_ID') == "B"]
print(chain)
sequence = [res for res in SEQ.findall('CHAIN') if res.findtext('RESIDUE/RES_POSITION') == "371"]
print(sequence)
for seq in chain:
    for res in sequence:
        if res == seq:
            print("=> %s" % res.findtext('RESIDUE/AA_CODE'))
```

- Since the sequence line now contains CHAIN elements, you have to find the RES_POSITION and AA_CODE elements by prefixing the RESIDUE element name.
- For the same reason you check res and seq for equality rather than for "containedness" (is this a word?).

One more suggestion - try this:

```
chain = [
    seq for seq in SEQ.findall('CHAIN')
    if seq.findtext('CHAIN_ID') == "B"
        and seq.findtext('RESIDUE/RES_POSITION') == "371"
] 
for seq in chain:
    print("=> %s" % seq.findtext('RESIDUE/AA_CODE'))
```

This is much more efficient because it only walks once through your entire data and does not require a nested for loop.

Comment: When I write SEQ.findall as you said, it returns empty list again.